# Where can I find the Apocalypse Now stem videos

Tags: murch, stems

I remember finding a great set of videos a while ago which broke down a scene from Apocalypse Now into the relevant stems (music, dialog, foley etc).

It was a great educational resource but I can't seem to find it. Anyone know if it's still online somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

http://transom.org/?page_id=7006

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that. Really recommend checking these out if you've not seen them.